# C# - Why do these namespaces clash?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing an app using Xamarin.Forms. I find that I am unable to get the following to compile:

```
namespace Loopback.Sdk.Xamarin.Example.Forms.Android
{
    [Activity (Label = "Loopback.Sdk.Xamarin.Example.Forms.Android.Android", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : AndroidActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);

            SetPage (App.GetMainPage ());
        }
    }
}
```

The build error is:

```
Loopback.Sdk.Xamarin.Example.Forms/Android/MainActivity.cs(4,4): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Forms' does not exist in the namespace `Loopback.Sdk.Xamarin'. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0234) (Loopback.Sdk.Xamarin.Example.Forms.Android)
```

Omitting `Xamarin`from the namespace declaration solves the issue, so I can only assume I am running into some kind of namespace clash. My question is why this happens, since the namespaces seemingly do not even have the same root?

UPDATE:

I should stress the part of the exception which nails down the error:

```
The type or namespace name `Forms' does not exist in the namespace `Loopback.Sdk.Xamarin'.
```

So to perhaps rephrase the question a bit, why `Loopback.Sdk.Xamarin` taken as the root namespace for `Forms`, rather than just `Xamarin`? How can I work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because you are using **Xamarin** in your namespace.

**Xamarin** is also a **root** namespace entry, hence it **can't** decide whether to go with your namespace hierarchy or the libraries for **Xamarin**.

If you must use **Xamarin** in your namespace, then you will have to qualify any references to the **Xamarin** namespace and give it an alternative name reference.

You can do this by putting something like:-

```
using XamarinForms = global::Xamarin.Forms;
```

as an example, and use this such like:-

```
XamarinForms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
```

Comment: I ended up using `using XForms = Xamarin.Forms.Forms;`, but this indeed solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is just how the compiler resolves namespaces. Given the presence of the namespace `Loopback.Sdk.Xamarin.Example.Forms.Android`, that implies all of the namespaces within that dotted syntax. This combined with the fact that C# allows you to use partially-qualified type names (i.e. a type name with part of but not all of the namespace) means that the compiler, having matched the `Xamarin` part of the namespace, assumes that `Xamarin.Forms` is part of the current namespace, which includes `Loopback.Sdk.Xamarin`. I.e. it assumes that the `Xamarin` in `Xamarin.Forms` actually refers to `Loopback.Sdk.Xamarin`.

Why are you fully-qualifying the type name `Xamarin.Forms.Forms`? If you have `using Xamarin.Forms;` as one of your `using` directives, then you should be able to just write `Forms.Init()` in your code and it will work.

Alternatively, you can use a type alias. For example `using Forms = Xamarin.Forms.Forms;`. That would also allow you to write `Forms.Init()` in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Some remarks: "Why are you fully-qualifying the type name Xamarin.Forms.Forms?" This code is generated by Xamarin, not by me. I tried including `using Xamarin.Forms;`, but unfortunately this does not solve the issue (still the same resolve problem). `using Forms = Xamarin.Forms.Forms;` did not work either. What finally solved it was using a unique identifier, i.e. `using XForms = Xamarin.Forms.Forms;`